# ASUS PB238Q Color RGB keeps changing

Tags: display, colors, display-settings, rgb

Following on from my previous question. Going into the. Menu I noticed that 2 of the colors were set to 100, whilst one was set to 0 hence the yellow tint. Anyway, I set all three colours to 100, everything went back to normal and then I turned the PC off.

The next time I turned the PC on the colour of the display was now RED, again I go into the color settings and one of the colors was back to ZERO whilst the other two were 100.

The monitor now does this everytime I turn it off and on again, it tweaks the colour settings meaning the display is tinted, Green, Blue, Red or Yellow.

I have no idea what is going on, could this be a firmware issue, if so how might I rule this out?

Comment: the setting you refer to are setting on the monitor itself correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct, I have to physically press the menu button on the monitor and go to the color settings to change everything back to normal each time i turn it on